# wp7 bing map on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to get any location on bing map on my wp7 emulator using GeoCoordinateWatcher, location service api. But my program can not return coordinates.I learned that location service api needs a real device to work, the emulator does not return any location data. Is there any way to do that in my emulator?

Comment: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/22/geo-location-services-in-windows-phone-7-developer-emulator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the arrows in the emulator to see these tools (location tab) :

[image]